# Send a mail to Administrator when creating a table in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to send a mail when user or the developers create an table in Database?

It will generate a mail and send it to the DBA to track.

Comment: Why not have your DBA create your tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have DBMail set up and configured correctly, you just need to execute the [sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) stored procedure.  Create a DDL trigger to fire this off for table creation.

Something like this:

```
create trigger TableCreatedSendMail
on database
for create_table
as
    sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'yourProfName',
        @recipients = 'yourRecipient@email.com',
        @body = 'some text here for the body',
        @subject = 'your subject';
go
```

Comment: can you please help me to configure my DBMail set up ?

Comment: @VikrantMore use this reference (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/) for a guide on setting up DBMail.